# SAS Add-In for Microsoft Office: Excel & Stored Process - don't show external database table in a separate tab

Tags: excel, vba, sas

In Excel I am executing a stored process that in last step creates a table in external database (Teradata):

```
data teradb.a;
set b;
run;
```

When this is executed, new sheet in Excel with its contents is also created. How can I prevent this from happening? 
I just want teradb.a to be created, don't need a separate worksheet in Excel with  it...

I execute stored process in vba using following code:

```
Dim SAS2 As SASExcelAddIn
Set SAS2 = Application.COMAddIns.Item("SAS.ExcelAddIn").Object
Dim streams As SASRanges
Set streams = New SASRanges
Sheets("Entry Criteria").Range("J9").Clear
streams.Add "XcelData", Sheets("Entry Criteria").Range(Cells(4, "D"), Cells(25, "F"))
SAS2.InsertStoredProcess "/system/UpdateParameters", Sheets("Entry Criteria").Range("J9"), , , streams
```

I was playing with ODS options or using proc sql with NOPRINT option, but this doesn't help.
Would highly appreciate your suggestions!

EDIT:
As requested - some screens with stored process properties :
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the properties of the Stored Process in the SAS Management Console ? In particular, in the Execution tab is Stream or Package checked ? Can you show more of the stored process source code ?

Comment: I have tried with checking/unchecking those options - result is the same. It is worth mentioning that when I create output dataset in work or any other SAS library, that I have assigned during stored process execution, everything works as intended - dataset is created and no additional info (apart from stored process status) is shown in Excel.

Comment: During the testing, are you pre-deleting (if exists) table `teradb.a` ? Remote data bases don't overwrite existing tables (SAS will overwrite native data sets unless NOREPLACE is active).  Is it possible the STP is logging any errors ?

Comment: Yes - I do delete that table if it exists before re-creating it. Code runs with no errors. Table is created as intended, the only problem is that a new spreadhseet with its contents is also created in Excel ( I don't need it). When output dataset is saved in SAS library instead of Teradata library, mentioned new spreadsheet is not created.

Comment: What is the name of the unexpected new sheet ?  Are you certain the parameters are correct ? Check the documentation https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=amodoccdc&cdcVersion=8.0&docsetId=amodg&docsetTarget=p1u415y2bdwtpsn1pt9hiyc27j45.htm&locale=en -- What happens if the output location (question shows `Sheets("Entry Criteria").Range("J9")`) is left blank ?

Comment: New sheet's name is just TERADB.A. I am not quite sure what do you mean by leaving output location blank - this is the location where date of last run is being shown: ""UpdateParameters" executed at 16/11/2018 15:57:31.". This gets overwritten with every execution, I am clearing it beforehand just to see that stored process is still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution turned out to be in the Tools -> Options of SAS ribbon in Excel.
Unchecking "Open output data automatically" under "Output Data Sets" section in "Data" tab did the trick.